# Trying to make asynchronous code run synchronously inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a function `runSyncForLoop`, in which I was hoping that the 2 second timeout would stop the `openEmailPage`from being called about 30 times in succession as `linkArray` is looped over. I did this based on a few other stackoverflow posts that I was reading through, one of which suggested `deasync` and another of which suggested `sync`. I think that the problem I am having is that `ret` is being set asynchronously, so this doesn't solve the problem. Right now, there is a pause, and then suddenly `openEmailPage` is fired the 30 times, although I was expecting there to be a two second delay between each fire.

```
function runSyncForLoop(linkArray){
    for (i in linkArray) {    
        var ret = 0 ;
        setTimeout(function(){
            openEmailPage(linkArray[i])  
        },2000); 
        ret="hello";   
    }    
    while(ret === 0) {
        require('deasync').runLoopOnce();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This could would simply be the following if it didn't have the deasync/timeout stuff:

```
function runSyncForLoop(linkArray){
    for (i in linkArray) {    
        openEmailPage(linkArray[i])  
    }    
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to run this with a two second delay between each call of `openEmailPage(linkArray[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout()` is asynchronous so all it does is start a timer and your `for` loop just keeps on running.  Thus, you end up setting 30 timers that all go off at about the same time.

Instead, you need to run your function, set a timer for two seconds and when that timer fires, run your function again.  Here's one way to do that:

```
function runEmailLoop(linkArray) {
    var cntr = 0;

    function run() {
        if (cntr < linkArray.length) {
            openEmailPage(linkArray[cntr]);
            ++cntr;
            setTimeout(run, 2000);
        }
    }
    // run first iteration immediately, then each one two seconds after that
    run();
}
```

---

If you want the first call to `openEmailPage()` to wait two seconds also, you can change it like this:

```
function runEmailLoop(linkArray) {
    var cntr = 0;

    function run() {
        if (cntr < linkArray.length) {
            openEmailPage(linkArray[cntr]);
            ++cntr;
            setTimeout(run, 2000);
        }
    }
    // run first iteration in 2 seconds
    setTimeout(run, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh that makes so much sense!